# ADT ошибка при компиляции

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?

[2013-11-09 21:10:23 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2013-11-09 21:10:23 - appTest] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

Информация на англоязычных ресурсах есть, но ответа полноценного нигде не нашёл.

Говорят откатиться к более старой версии. Как это произвести? Скачать другую сборку или как?)

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть несколько:

1. У Вас разные версии одного и того же jar-файла в зависимостях проекта(посмотрите внимательно в Java Build path)
2. Если это ADT 22.0, то нужно обновиться до 22.3. Укажите версию ADT в вопросе.
3. Попробовать сделать Clean, хотя это врят ли поможет, но все же.
4. Перезапустить Eclipse после всех попыток. Иногда помогает чудесным образом. Но все же ошибка скорее всего в библиотеке(jar-архив)

Answer (score 0):

Где то читал что нужно использовать jdk 6 а не 7

Comment: Не где-нибудь, а в системных требованиях на Android SDK [указан](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) JDK 6

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй правой кнопкой мыши на проекте - Android Tools - Add support Library...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить папку android-4.4 в директории SDK папка build-tools

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727915/android-dex-gives-a-bufferoverflowexception-when-building
Мне помогло вот это
No need to downgrade the build tools back to 18.1.1

Make sure that the value of android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml matches target=android- in project.properties. If these two values are not the same, building with build tools version 19.0.0 will end in the BufferOverflowException

По ссылке автора поста есть пример